# javascript: log-in to a website

Tags: javascript, cookies, authentication

im trying to write a piece of code that lets a user to log in to a website that uses a cookie based login process .

the website is this : `www.sess.shirazu.ac.ir`

but the problem is it gives the user a cookie and for the user to stay `loged-in` i need to have that `cookie` for sending more `requests` .

now the question is how can i log in to this website while having the `cookie` for sending more request to the server ?

Comment: why you want to realize login functionality with client side JavaScript?

Comment: im writing an android app for that website using react native which uses javascript .